# Bootstrap Validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap Validator in my project.

My form is in a modal and is sent through ajax. I've used the example code to validate and send the form, but when clicking on the button that should send the form nothing happens. The validation works fine but I can't get into:

```
.on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
```

I've managed to recreate it here => [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c22mutrn/)

When you click on 'Opslaan' (= 'Save') nothing happens.

I only have validation on Naam (Name) for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form never gets submited because your button with type="submit" is outside your form element. Put this inside the form and it will fire away!

Like so:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formAddRelation" role="form">
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
    <button type="submit" id="saverelation" class="btn btn- primary">Opslaan</button>
</form>
```